# Parsing docx with SwiftSoup and SSZipArchive yields unexpected results due to "gramstart" tag

Tags: swift, parsing, docx, ssziparchive, swiftsoup

I retrieve a docx via a web service call. I then unzip it with SSZipArchive. From there, I parse it with SwiftSoup. See code below

```
    if let xmlURL = self.extractDocxAttachment(data: data) {
        let string = self.getStringFrom(docURL: xmlURL)
        print(string)
    } else {
        print("Could not convert doc")
    }

 func extractDocxAttachment(data: Data) -> URL? {
        print(#function)
        
        do {
            // Save ZIP data to a temporary file
            let tempZipURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory()).appendingPathComponent("temp.zip")
            try data.write(to: tempZipURL)
            
            // Extract ZIP archive using SSZipArchive
            let destinationDir = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory()).appendingPathComponent("extracted-docx")
            let success = SSZipArchive.unzipFile(atPath: tempZipURL.path, toDestination: destinationDir.path)
            
            // Clean up temporary ZIP file
            try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: tempZipURL)
            
            if success {
                // Get URL of word/document.xml file
                let documentXMLFileURL = destinationDir.appendingPathComponent("word").appendingPathComponent("document.xml")
                return documentXMLFileURL
            } else {
                print("Failed to extract DOCX file.")
                return nil
            }
        } catch {
            print("Error extracting DOCX file: \(error)")
            return nil
        }
    }
    
    func getStringFrom(docURL: URL) -> String {
        print(#function)
        
        // Initialize an ordered set to store unique text content while preserving order
        var uniqueTexts = OrderedSet<String>()
        
        do {
            // Read XML file as string
            let xmlString = try String(contentsOf: docURL, encoding: .utf8)
            
            // Parse the XML string using SwiftSoup
            let document = try SwiftSoup.parse(xmlString)
            
            // Extract text content from XML document, preserving newline characters
            let elements = try document.select("body *").array() // Select all elements inside <body>
            for element in elements {
                // Get text content of the element
                let elementText = try element.text()
                
                // Insert non-empty element texts into the ordered set
                if !elementText.isEmpty {
                    uniqueTexts.insert(elementText)
                }
            }
        } catch {
            // Handle any parsing or file reading errors and print an error message
            print("Error parsing XML file \(docURL.lastPathComponent): \(error)")
        }
        
        // Return the concatenated XML text with newline characters
        return uniqueTexts.arrayRepresentation().joined(separator: "\n")
    }
struct OrderedSet<T: Hashable> {
private var array = [T]()
private var set = Set<T>()

mutating func insert(_ element: T) {
    if !set.contains(element) {
        array.append(element)
        set.insert(element)
    }
}

func arrayRepresentation() -> [T] {
    return array

}
```

The problem I'm having is that the parsed data is being split up strangely because of something called "gramStart." When I look at the XML, I can see that it sometimes separates out the last word or words of a given line. For example, see below:

```
<w:t xml:space="preserve">4 cups cooked white </w:t>
</w:r>
<w:proofErr w:type="gramStart"/>
<w:r w:rsidRPr="0052776F">
<w:rPr>
<w:rFonts w:ascii="Helvetica" w:hAnsi="Helvetica"/>
<w:kern w:val="0"/>
<w:sz w:val="27"/>
<w:szCs w:val="27"/>
<w14:ligatures w14:val="none"/>
</w:rPr>
<w:t>rice</w:t>
</w:r>
<w:proofErr w:type="gramEnd"/>
</w:p>
```

From what I can tell from [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.wordprocessing.prooferror?view=openxml-2.8.1), that tag occurs when Word has flagged a phrase as needing grammar checking for some reason. This is ruining my parsing because it interprets those as separate lines - i.e. I receive:

4 cups cooked white
rice

My question is, how can I avoid this? Can I either, 1). get SwiftSoup to ignore that tag, 2). get ZipArchive, when unzipping, to ignore that tag, or 3). use different extensions to do this instead?

Thanks!